# Howto get parent id of drag and drop target div?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a container div (module) on which I drop another div (room) and on this div i drop another div (person). I can get the id of the room when i drop the person on it (theEvent.target.id), but is it also possible to get the id of the module div - the outer container ?? I'm using the HTML5 drag and drop features.

Comment: Is this Java? or JavaScript?

Comment: OK, I see that the Java tag has been removed and JavaScript placed instead. Hopefully you understand the difference, but if not, you'll want to read up on this because it is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the DOM tree back and retrieve the ID of the container.

```
<div id="room1234">
   <div id="person4321">...</div>
</div>
```

When you detect that "person4321" is dropped on, get the roomid:

```
var roomid=document.getElementById(event.target.id).parentNode.id;
```

If you're ready to work with the room directly, skip the "id" part and work with the object directly:

```
var room=document.getElementById(event.target.id).parentNode;
```

Now your room doesn't even need an ID!

Edit:

Even better, you can omit the person's ID too:

```
var room = event.target.parentNode;
```